# Redirect to new view with submit_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, submit, link-to

I have the following `submit_tag` button

`<%= submit_tag("Save Email".upcase, name:"email_change","data-target":"email_change.submit") %>`

I am trying to have it redirect to a new view, similar to what is done with using `link_to`. Is there a way to do something similar using the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<% link_to some_path do %>
  <%= submit_tag("Save Email".upcase, name:"email_change","data-target":"email_change.submit") %>
<% end %>
```

The 'Rails' way to do this would probably be to wrap the redirect in some conditional logic in your controller action, especially if you're submitting data from a form